# Algorithmically selecting colors that will contrast with their background

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

I am trying to write an implementation of a color quantization algorithm in order to find an image's dominant colors (say 5) and then find contrasting colors based on the colors found in the image.

I've tried implementing a k-means algorithm but the result ends up differently every time.

What do you suggest? I need help mostly with the color segmentation. What algorithm/method do you suggest? I can play with picking contrasting colors on my own.

I am able to iterate through an image's individual rgb values on a per-pixel basis.

Side note: The language I am using is objective C, so there are no libraries (that I know of) that can perform this task.

**How I used the K-Means algorithm:**

1. create array of pixels with an R, G, B value.
2. choose 5 random pixels as clusters (c)
3. assign each pixel to the closest c in 3 dimensional space using 3d distance equation
4. change cluster locations (c) to the average of the r, g, and b values of it's assigned points
5. repeat steps 3&4 for a while

Comment: Hi NickPlace and welcome to Scicomp!  Could you add more information about the k-means algorithm you used into your question.  This may help to understand why the algorithm produces very different results.

Comment: Okay, I added it.

Comment: Your different results each time are due to your random point choice in step 2.  In step 5, are you re-choosing your cluster points as well?  Also, how many iterations are you running of the algorithm? At the very least you can seed your random number generator with a constant until you get it "working" to avoid the varying results.

Comment: @Nick: it sounds like you are looking to do image segmentation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_(image_processing). If not, how do the results you seek differ from the results that one obtains with image segmentation?

Answer (score 5):

RGB distance is not at all close to [Color difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) (but don't be put off by the formulas there).
Basically you want to transform your RGB triples to [Lab color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space), and use distances there:

```
def rgb_deltae76( rgb, rgb2 ):
    return distance( rgb_lab(rgb), rgb_lab(rgb2) )
```

`rgb_lab` is a couple of pages of Python, somebody must have code in objective C;
try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colors.

Added: [this note](http://www.compuphase.com/cmetric.htm) gives the approximation 
$\sqrt { 3 (R - R')^2 + 4 (G - G')^2 + 2 (B - B')^2 }$
and another better one.
See also [Munsell color system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munsell_color_system)
and [triplecode.com/munsell](http://www.triplecode.com/munsell):
"The Munsell system is different because it is based on how people *perceive* colors."

Answer (score 0):

Can you transform your RGB colors to some other color notation, like [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) ? The *H* would be the color, be it a radial measure ( 0 -360 degrees) or some value. Then use the value that maximizes the distance to the colors you have.